# Replace 1s with column names in a dataframe

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
df<-data.frame(
 hhid = c(5668,5595,4724,4756,4856,4730,4757,6320,4758,6319,6311,5477,6322),

 pid=c(93660,93660,100960,100960,100960,100960,100960,100962,100960,100962,100962,93814,100962),

 pname=c("AB","HG","DC","DC","DC","DC","DC","BA","DC","BA","BA","BH","BA"),

 vid=c(462962,608757,772284,772284,772284,293475,293475,656323,293475,656323,81533,465612,656323),

 vname=c("ABCD","KJUI","HIND","HIND","HIND","KAJA","KAJA","ADAR","KAJA","ADAR","SANG","NARI","ADAR"),

 me=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),

 ls=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),

 lg=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),

 lo=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),

 amt=c(20000,20000,14000,14000,14000,14000,14000,27000,14000,27000,27000,20000,23000))
```

There are more than 20000 rows in this data. hhid,pid,pname,vid,vname,ls,lg,lo,amt are column names. Every hhid is unique.

The output that i need is this:

```
hhid   pid      pname      vid        vname       LOS         amt
5668    93660     AB      462962    ABCD          me         20000
5595    93660     HG      608757    KJUI          me         20000
4724    100960    DC      772284    HIND          ls         14000
4756    100960    DC      772284    HIND          ls         14000
4856    100960    DC      772284    HIND          lo         14000
and so on.
```

So basically what i want is replacing 1 in me , ls ,lg , lo columns with a NEW COLUMN LOS which contains column name me, ls, lg, lo as the new row data.That is replacing 1s with Column names and saving that to a new column LOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df$LOS <- c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo")[apply(df[, c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo")]==1, 1, which)]
# > df
#    hhid    pid pname    vid vname me ls lg lo   amt LOS
# 1  5668  93660    AB 462962  ABCD  1  0  0  0 20000  me
# 2  5595  93660    HG 608757  KJUI  1  0  0  0 20000  me
# 3  4724 100960    DC 772284  HIND  0  1  0  0 14000  ls
# 4  4756 100960    DC 772284  HIND  0  1  0  0 14000  ls
# 5  4856 100960    DC 772284  HIND  0  0  0  1 14000  lo
# 6  4730 100960    DC 293475  KAJA  0  1  0  0 14000  ls
# 7  4757 100960    DC 293475  KAJA  0  0  1  0 14000  lg
# 8  6320 100962    BA 656323  ADAR  1  0  0  0 27000  me
# 9  4758 100960    DC 293475  KAJA  0  1  0  0 14000  ls
# 10 6319 100962    BA 656323  ADAR  0  0  1  0 27000  lg
# 11 6311 100962    BA  81533  SANG  0  0  0  1 27000  lo
# 12 5477  93814    BH 465612  NARI  1  0  0  0 20000  me
# 13 6322 100962    BA 656323  ADAR  0  1  0  0 23000  ls
```

or (defining a vector of columnnames)

```
cols <- c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo")
df$LOS <- cols[apply(df[, cols]==1, 1, which)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the data into longer format and `filter` the rows with `value = 1`

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = c(me, ls, lg, lo), names_to = "LOS") %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value)

#   hhid    pid pname    vid vname   amt LOS 
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  5668  93660 AB    462962 ABCD  20000 me   
# 2  5595  93660 HG    608757 KJUI  20000 me   
# 3  4724 100960 DC    772284 HIND  14000 ls   
# 4  4756 100960 DC    772284 HIND  14000 ls   
# 5  4856 100960 DC    772284 HIND  14000 lo   
# 6  4730 100960 DC    293475 KAJA  14000 ls   
# 7  4757 100960 DC    293475 KAJA  14000 lg   
# 8  6320 100962 BA    656323 ADAR  27000 me   
# 9  4758 100960 DC    293475 KAJA  14000 ls   
#10  6319 100962 BA    656323 ADAR  27000 lg   
#11  6311 100962 BA     81533 SANG  27000 lo   
#12  5477  93814 BH    465612 NARI  20000 me   
#13  6322 100962 BA    656323 ADAR  23000 ls
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
df <- transform(df[!(names(df) %in% c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo"))], 

                name = names(df)[(names(df) %in% c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo"))][apply(df[(names(df) %in% c("me", "ls", "lg", "lo"))], 1, which.max)])
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(

  hhid = c(5668,5595,4724,4756,4856,4730,4757,6320,4758,6319,6311,5477,6322),

  pid=c(93660,93660,100960,100960,100960,100960,100960,100962,100960,100962,100962,93814,100962),

  pname=c("AB","HG","DC","DC","DC","DC","DC","BA","DC","BA","BA","BH","BA"),

  vid=c(462962,608757,772284,772284,772284,293475,293475,656323,293475,656323,81533,465612,656323),

  vname=c("ABCD","KJUI","HIND","HIND","HIND","KAJA","KAJA","ADAR","KAJA","ADAR","SANG","NARI","ADAR"),

  me=c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),

  ls=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),

  lg=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0),

  lo=c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),

  amt=c(20000,20000,14000,14000,14000,14000,14000,27000,14000,27000,27000,20000,23000))
```